# How to test in VSCode a postgreSQL SQL expression in Python's interactive notebook (= Jupyter Notebook, iPython) in a venv with package manager conda?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, anaconda, ipython

How to test in VSCode a postgreSQL SQL expression in Python's interactive notebook (= Jupyter Notebook, iPython) in a venv with package manager conda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Sharing this since it took me too long to set this up from the scattered guides and hints.*

---

- Change to a conda environment of your choice. For example, make a virtual environment called *venv310* (same name in the whole answer) with `conda create -n venv310 python=3.10` and activate it with: `conda activate venv310`.

If I open VSCode from a terminal that has activated the venv310, VSCode falls back to the base env as soon as I run code with *Shift+Enter*:

```shell
(base) … $ /bin/python3
Python 3.10.6 (main, Nov 14 2022, 16:10:14) [GCC 11.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from sqlalchemy import create_engine

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlalchemy'
```

- Without having the *venv310* at work here, it is already clear from this error that the mistakenly taken base environment would need the sqlalchemy module, so that we need to install in the *venv310*:

```shell
conda install sqlalchemy
```

- And from a later error it turns out that you also need to install the dialect "psycopg2":

```shell
    raise exc.NoSuchModuleError(
sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:postgres.psycopg2
```

```shell
conda install psycopg2
```

- If you run magic like '%load_ext sql' instead, you will see:

```shell
>>> %load_ext sql
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    %load_ext sql
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

- Anyway, the main problem is that the virtual environment does not work. Thus, install VSCode/VSCodium extension "Python for VSCode".
  See [Activating Anaconda Environment in VsCode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43352598/11154841).
- Restart VSCode.
- Click *Yes* if you see this:

[image]

> We noticed you're using a conda environment. If you are experiencing
> issues with this environment in the integrated terminal, we recommend
> that you let the Python extension change
> "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv" to false in your user settings.
>
> Source: Python (Extension) Yes No More Info

- Press *Ctrl+Shift+P* → "Python: Select interpreter" → choose *venv310* (this is what I could already do before, but now, when running some code, it did not fall back to the base env).
  See [Activating Anaconda Environment in VsCode - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43351596/activating-anaconda-environment-in-vscode).
- Open the interactive Window with *Ctrl+Shift+P* → "Jupyter: Create Interactive Window"

[image]

I started the interactive window just with a right-click on the `%load_ext sql` line that I had in the normal Python code editor. Or you press *Shift+Enter* in that line.

See [How do I find/excute Python Interactive Mode in Visual Studio Code? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64730660/how-do-i-find-excute-python-interactive-mode-in-visual-studio-code).

Then it shows:

[image]

> Running cells with 'Python 3.10.6 ('venv310')' requires ipykernel package.

Click *Install*.

- Not sure but I think I clicked *Install*, and it still showed in the iPython history:

[image]

> Running cells with 'Python 3.10.6 ('venv310')' requires ipykernel package.
> Run the following command to install 'ipykernel' into the Python environment.
> Command: 'conda install -n venv310 ipykernel --update-deps --force-reinstall'
>
> # %%
> Python 3.10.8 (main, Nov 24 2022, 14:13:03) [GCC 11.2.0]
> Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
> IPython 8.7.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

Thus, if you see this as well, run `conda install -n venv310 ipykernel --update-deps --force-reinstall` in the *venv310*.

- Run `%load_ext sql` in the iPython terminal, either by typing it in the terminal, or by running the magic from the Python editor (check right-click to see how to run in interactive window).

[image]

[image]

If you see:

[image]

```shell
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                     Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 1
----> 1 get_ipython().run_line_magic('load_ext', 'sql')

File ~/anaconda3/envs/venv310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:2364, in InteractiveShell.run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line, _stack_depth)
   2362     kwargs['local_ns'] = self.get_local_scope(stack_depth)
   2363 with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2364     result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
   2365 return result

File ~/anaconda3/envs/venv310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/extension.py:33, in ExtensionMagics.load_ext(self, module_str)
    31 if not module_str:
    32  raise UsageError('Missing module name.')
---> 33 res = self.shell.extension_manager.load_extension(module_str)
    35 if res == 'already loaded':
    36  print("The %s extension is already loaded. To reload it, use:" % module_str)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/venv310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/extensions.py:76, in ExtensionManager.load_extension(self, module_str)
    69 """Load an IPython extension by its module name.
    70
    71 Returns the string "already loaded" if the extension is already loaded,
    72 "no load function" if the module doesn't have a load_ipython_extension
    73 function, or None if it succeeded.
    74 """
...
File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1027, in _find_and_load(name, import_)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sql'
```

or if you run the following magic and see one of these:

```shell
# %%
%sql postgresql+psycopg2://localhost/&server=postgres?user=postgres&port=5432&password=postgres&database=test_db
UsageError: Line magic function `%sql` not found.

# %%
%%sql select * FROM x;
UsageError: Cell magic `%%sql` not found.

# %%
result = %sql select * FROM x;
UsageError: Line magic function `%sql` not found.
```

then you need to run in the *venv310*:

```
conda install -c conda-forge ipython-sql
```

*(and not the pip installer `pipenv install ipython-sql` like it is written in the [ipython-sql guide](https://jupyter-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/stable/data-processing/postgresql/ipython-sql.html))*

See [UsageError: Line magic function `%sql` not found - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63882681/usageerror-line-magic-function-sql-not-found)

- Back in VSCode, you might see:

[image]

But that does not harm.

- Run again:

```shell
%load_ext sql
```

[image]

- And then:
  %sql postgresql+psycopg2://localhost/&server=postgres?user=postgres&port=5432&password=postgres&database=test_db

[image]

(See: [What is the format for the PostgreSQL connection string / URL? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582552/what-is-the-format-for-the-postgresql-connection-string-url))

- And now, you can see the SQL output in the iPython console:

```shell
%sql select * FROM x;
```

[image]

with the output afterwards. For a displaylimit, see the [ipython-sql guide](https://jupyter-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/stable/data-processing/postgresql/ipython-sql.html#configuration) --> "Configuration".

Comment: Very good self solved answer. FWIW, the whole explanation you posted in the question is better suited for the answer. So I removed it from the question and placed it here. Good work!